# Extra user_id in junction table for simplicity

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
foo(id, ..., user_id)
bar(id, ...)
foo_bar(foo_id, bar_id)
```

I need to select a row from 'foo_bar' and check if the record belongs to a specific user. Is it good practice to add a 'user_id' column to 'foo_bar' table so that I could run a query:

```
// 1 query only 
$foobar = SELECT * FROM foo_bar WHERE foo_id = ? AND bar_id = ? AND user_id = ?
```

instead of first querying 'foo' table to check if 'foo' record belongs to user and then running a second query to select the 'foo_bar' record?
Something like this:

```
// 2 queries
$userId = SELECT user_id FROM foo WHERE foo_id = ?;
if ($userId === $userIdToCompareTo) {
    $foobar = SELECT * FROM foo_bar WHERE foo_id = ? AND bar_id = ?
}
```

Does this make sense or is this usually handled another way with a more complex query?

Comment: It depends what you mean by belongs to a specific user. Using real examples. foo could be blog posts, bar could be tags. Multiple **posts** can have the same **tags** and/or different ones, so the relation would be foo_bar. But **belongs to** in this case might be the one who created the post, or created the tag, or created the relationship betweem them. In your example, foo belongs to one user, but foo_bar have different belongs depending where you are looking.

Comment: In my example, you can replace `foo` with `recipe` and `bar` with `food` so `foo_bar` would be `recipe_food`. In order for the user to delete a `recipe_food` record, I must first check whether the user actually owns the recipe. I could do it with a JOIN like suggested by Gordon Linoff or I could do it by adding an extra column. Which would be better in your opinion?

Comment: Definitely by JOIN. But consider soft deletes before permament deletes on this case, maybe the user deleted it but is not exactly sure yet, he might just edit the recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not.  You should look up the value using a `join`:

```
select . . . 
from foo_bar fb join
     foo f
     on fb.foo_id = f.id
where f.user_id = ?;
```

A key principle of data modeling is that you should store data in only one place.  That is, if you store the `user_id` in `foo_bar`, then what happens if the `user_id` changes?  Or if the `foo` record is deleted?

There are some situations where you would want to replicate the user id.  In particular, if the user id *does* change, you might want to capture the `user_id` on `foo_bar` at the moment when the record is created.  I only bring this up because it is important to understand principles and to understand when they don't necessarily apply.

Comment: @Rafael . . . Jon Skeet is and probably always will be the Primo Contributor on the site:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet.

Comment: The `user_id` will never change in my use case and if `foo` record is deleted, then `foo_bar` record will also be deleted because it doesn't make sense for `foo_bar` record to exist if either `foo` or `bar` record is deleted.

In my scenario, the `user_id` column is only there to check for user being the owner of this record. It really serves no other purpose.

Comment: @i3x37 . . . You should still use a `JOIN` to look up the value.  This should be a very fast operation, assuming your database is set up correctly.